# Does K8s has some little tool projects that provide service/portallocator&allocator functions

Tags: go, kubernetes, cloud

Our project needs to allocate some ports for pods in **K8s**. So we introduced `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/registry/core/service/allocator` and `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/registry/core/service/portallocator`. But it **strongly depends on K8s** which may cause update and security problems. So I wonder if there are some official tool packages which can **allocate some ports for pods**, or if there are some other solutions?

we need to use `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/registry/core/service/portallocator`'s `Allocate()`, `Release()` and `AllocateNext()` function.to allocate ports for pods out of a range.